# Mac App distribution Invalid Binary issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, itunes-store

I am trying to upload my mac xcode project on mac app store, but each-time it shows invalid binary status. I have checked many answers in stack overflow as well. But issue  is not resolved. That's why I am posting new question here

I tried some options -

**1.. Removed all warnings**

**2.. Checked by quiting xcode, cleaned container folder**

**3.. provisioning profile is valid, and matching to the bundle id. I checked by deleting all certificates and provisioning and install required ones again.**

**4.. Created new provisioning profile and certificate 3 times. But same issue**

**5.. uploaded 3 times directly through xcode 5.1.1, and 2 times by Application Loader. But showing Invalid binary for all.**

**6.. App is properly sandboxed with proper permissions**

Any idea. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Invalid Binary

When you get this error, apple will send you a mail with reason. In my case this was the email:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "App-Name". To process your delivery, the following issues must be
>   corrected:
>
> App sandbox not enabled - The following executables must include the
>   "com.apple.security.app-sandbox" entitlement with a Boolean value of
>   true in the entitlements property list. Refer to the App Sandbox page
>   for more information on sandboxing your app.
>
> ```
> App-name Mac.app/Contents/MacOS/app-name
> ```
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the
>   corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

---

Also, you shouldn't be using XCode `5.1.1` itunes connect has changed a lot now.

Please update to `6.0.1` or use the new beta version `6.1`

[**Xcode 6.1 GM seed for OS X Yosemite**](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/)

hope this helps

Comment: @Student are you signing properly, is your plist file correct. where do you get the error itunes connect or xcode

Comment: I have validated build before upload. As i mentioned in question, i hecked the provisioning multiple times. There is no error, Just the problem is -- on itunes connect its showing Invalid Binary for all builds.

Comment: @Student when this happens apple will send you an email with the reason why it is invalid. please check your inbox. it happened to me once due to sandbox but you said you did that already

Comment: Ok thank you sir for your concern. I'll check mail and mention you in case of any problem.

Comment: @Student Im pretty sure solution will be there as this could be due to various reason. let me know we will figure it out

Comment: Thanks Sir, apple mail has the exact reason (image name problem). My app is submitted now :)